# Audio volume goes from 0 to 100 on aux (basically only on/off)

Tags: linux, audio

When I play audio on my `aux` headphone output, when the master-volume is 0% no sound is heard, no problem there. However, when I go to 1% or anything between that and 100%, the volume is at 100%, and doesn't change in audible volume/db, until it goes over 100%, like 115% it's audibly louder.

So basically the audio goes from 0 to 100. While the internal sound volume (it's a laptop) works fine. And it switches between them automatically fine when I plug in a headphone.

Also, this is not a an issue with the hardware itself, because this has work normally before and still works fine with windows 10. (I think it even might have something to do with `i3`, because I think it worked fine with Cinnamon)

I've tried googling this issue, but I can't find any prior cases or the right search terms to use.

When I open `pavucontrol` I can control the volume there per application, that is the only way to control the volume, but not with the master volume.

This might help:

```
❱ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: me2 Kernel: 4.10.0-35-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: i3 4.14.1 Distro: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
Machine:   Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-17B1 v: REV:1.0
           Bios: American Megatrends v: E17B1IMS.310 date: 04/07/2017
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-7700HQ (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 22464
           clock speeds: max: 2700 MHz 1: 2800 MHz 2: 2800 MHz 3: 2800 MHz 4: 2800 MHz
           5: 2800 MHz 6: 2800 MHz 7: 2800 MHz 8: 2800 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 591b bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1c20 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 driver: nvidia
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 3840x2160@60.00hz, 1920x1080@59.93hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2
           GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.66 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Device a171 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-35-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 driver: alx port: d000 bus-ID: 3d:00.0
           IF: enp61s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath10k_pci bus-ID: 3e:00.0
           IF: wlp62s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-3: Atheros usb-ID: 001-007
           IF: null-if-id state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 2000.4GB (5.6% used)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: N/A size: 512.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/sda model: ST2000LM015 size: 2000.4GB
           ID-3: /dev/mmcblk0 model: N/A size: 124.5GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 119G used: 17G (15%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
           ID-2: /home size: 67G used: 60G (94%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 32.00GB used: 0.19GB (1%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 62.5C mobo: 27.8C gpu: 0.0:48C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 392 Uptime: 1 day Memory: 12399.8/15929.3MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (zsh 5.1.1) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Output of `pacmd info`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1911641574d8a511fc4d7e2d09d5c3f

A more extensive thread of this problem: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=256467&p=1385313#p1385313 see the replies.

So in summary

- The internal speakers don't mute when I plug in the headphones (this is a different issue than this post)
- The internal speakers work fine with the master volume.
- The AUX output is not shown in `Output Devices` which might be the main problem here.
- The AUX volume only changes when the main volume is above 100%
- The AUX volume can only be changed by changing the volume of the source app, or under the `Playback` tab in pavucontrol.
- Under configuration tab in pavucontrol the profile `Analogue Stereo Duplex` or `Analogue Stereo Output` gives me sound through the AUX, the others don't

Comment: does the command line work : `pactl set-sink-volume 0 -50%` or `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +50%`?

Comment: @GAD3R, yes and it will do the same thing as my master control is now doing. In Pavucontrol, the "pop" sound I hear when I manually move the slider, will also be the same volume, except above 100%

Comment: I solved the output problem

Selecting `Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output` will mute my speakers, and the master volume will work on the AUX.

For some reason the `Output Devices` port will say `S/PDIF`, while it is not an optical plug, just a stereo jack.

Anyways, now I'll just need to find a way to detect the plugging in of the AUX which is a different topic entirely.

I hesitate to close the issue, since the 0 to 100% is still strange and not expected behaviour.