# Audio stereo jack plugin not detected

Tags: audio, alsa

Let me start of by clarifying that my stereo jack audio output is detected/listed as an `IEC958`/`S/PDIF` device, but it's not an optical output, it's a standard stereo jack. This might already be the cause of the problem.

On Windows plugging/unplugging detection works fine, and it has worked before on linux (using Mint 4.10.0-35-generic) but on other WMs, currently using `i3`, but I think it's unrelated to the WM, and something else might have changed in the meantime. I don't remember installing any drivers for the audio, it already worked.

### The problem

I can't get the audio jack plugin/unplug event to fire.

#### What does work

Manually switching with `pavucontrol` to Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (`iec985-stereo-output`) will mute my speakers (`analog-output-speaker`) and give me audio and volume control on the jack. Good.

There is no other option in the list that will give my jack exclusive audio (so speakers muted). (Other than this other issue I was dealing with first, until I found out I had to switch to the `IEC958` output: [Audio volume goes from 0 to 100 on aux (basically only on/off)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402080/audio-volume-goes-from-0-to-100-on-aux-basically-only-on-off) & https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=256467&p=1391958#p1391958 but that's an entirely different rabbit hole to go down) but anyway.

## Testing audiojack events

I think I've exhausted ways to test the events

### evtest:

```
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event3:  Power Button
/dev/input/event4:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event5:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event6:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event7:  Logitech MX Master 2S
/dev/input/event8:  ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
/dev/input/event9:  Metadot - Das Keyboard Das Keyboard
/dev/input/event10: Metadot - Das Keyboard Das Keyboard
/dev/input/event11: MSI WMI hotkeys
/dev/input/event12: NEC HD WebCam
/dev/input/event13: HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event14: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event15: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event16: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
```

14, 15, 16 are not detecting anything at all. 13 does trigger when I plug it into the mic, so at least that one works.

### acpi_listen

```
❱ acpi_listen
```

nothing...
But for the microphone:

```
jack/microphone MICROPHONE plug
jack/microphone MICROPHONE unplug
```

### diff events

From what I understand we can mock the events with:

```
sudo cat /proc/asound/card0/codec\#0 > unplugged
sudo cat /proc/asound/card0/codec\#0 > plugged
diff unplugged plugged
```

But the diff outputs nothing.

## Hardware

### pacmd

```
❱ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name' -e 'index'

  * index: 68
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo>
        alsa.name = "ALC898 Digital"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf120000 irq 133"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC898"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

Longer list

```
❱ pacmd list-sinks                            

1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 68
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9958
    volume: front-left: 44895 /  69% / -9.86 dB,   front-right: 44895 /  69% / -9.86 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 19.98 ms
    max request: 4 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 82
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 5
    configured latency: 23.22 ms; range is 0.50 .. 371.52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC898 Digital"
        alsa.id = "ALC898 Digital"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "1"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf120000 irq 133"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a171"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "iec958:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC898"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0899,146211ac,00100003 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

    active port: <iec958-stereo-output>
```

### aplay

```
❱ aplay -l                                                                 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC898 Analog [ALC898 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC898 Digital [ALC898 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

### lsmod

```
❱ lsmod | grep '^snd' | column -t                  
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152   1
snd_hda_codec_realtek  90112   1
snd_hda_codec_generic  73728   1   snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864   7
snd_hda_codec          126976  4   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920   5   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384   1   snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                102400  6   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi           16384   0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384   1   snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768   1   snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536   2   snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384   3   snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768   2   snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    77824   23  snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
```

## Not sure it's relevant, but I'll share it anyways:

Alsa mixer shows S/PDIF at 0:

[image: Alsa mixer shows S/PDIF at 0]

While pavucontrol show the correct volume for the audio jack

[image]

I have only 1 device in alsamixer:

[image]

Oh, and when I select Analogue Stereo Duplex/Output, I can't select any different port under `Output Devices`, Only "Speakers", I suspect that it should list the audio jack as a port, but it don't.

Also, when open cinnamon audio settings it shows only these 2 as separate audio sources: 
[image]

## Update

Outputs of:

### hdajacksensetest

```
❱ sudo hdajacksensetest
Pin 0x18 (Black Mic, Rear side): present = Yes
```

### hdajackretask

[image]

#### Tried overriding with `hdajackretask`

[image]

But still no detection...

### amixer

```
❱ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-65.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Front',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Surround',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Center',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'LFE',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Side',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 87
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 87 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Default PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',16
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Beep',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 63
  Front Left: Capture 50 [79%] [20.25dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 50 [79%] [20.25dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Loopback Mixing',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
```

Answer (score 3):

Guess: The BIOS is lying about the assignment of the jacks, and you are missing a "quirk" in the drivers to work around that, or when you updated you got a quirk that doesn't fit your situation.

In Windows this doesn't matter, because the pre-installed driver ignores the BIOS information and uses the correct (known) assignment.

Have a look at `hdajackretask` and `hdajacksensetest` (package `alsa-tools-gui` on Debian etc.) and see if you can fix the assignment. Information about what the codec things the assignment is can be found with `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`. There you can also see if the jack is configured to emit "unsoliticed events" (aka plug events).

Comment: `sudo hdajacksensetest`: `Pin 0x18 (Black Mic, Rear side): present = No`. Getting no other pins. Not sure what to do with `hdajackretask`. I can only select `override and say `disconnected` for the SPDIF out

Comment: I've updated my question with some additional output, and tried overriding the jack, but to no avail.

Comment: Is there a way to detect any events on the `unconnected pins` somehow? `acpi_listen` etc don't..

Comment: I used `hdajacksensetest --allpins` before **and** after plugging in the jack to get a clear view of state changes. For some reason, one of the pins was never shown, even if present. Then I used `hdajackretask` to repurpose the pins (with _Show unconnected pins_ and _Advanced override_ options set)

Comment: My configuration currently looks like: _0x19:Conn.=Jack;Location=Left;Device=Microphone;Jack=3.5mm;Color=Black;Jack detection=Present;Channel group=4;Channel (in group)=Channel 30 & 31;;0x21:Conn.=Jack;Location=Left;Device=Headphone;Jack=3.5;Color=Black;Jack detection=Present;Channel group=3;Channel (in group)=Channel 30 & 31_